# How to redistribute probabilities when one outcome's probabilities changes

Tags: probability

Let's say that one scenario has 3 possible outcomes A, B and C, for each outcome there's a 33% chance of it happening, however, if suddenly A's chances changed to 80%, how would I redistribute the chances among the remaining outcomes?

My first thought would be to split the remaining evenly between B and C, however this would not suffice if the initial chances for B and C weren't the same.

With that in mind is there a way to redistribute the chances correctly even if B / C weren't initially the same?

Notes:

*For this specific question only one outcome will change with a predefined chance.

*There can be n number of outcomes with x chances of each occurring initially.

Comment: You want the remaining changes to be kept in the same ratio? Then you just to normalize them again. Say the original probability is $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ and now $p_1$ change to $p^*_1$. then you will need the new $p^*_i$ satisfy $\sum_{i=2}^n p^*_i = 1 - p^*_1$. To kept $p^*_2, \ldots, p^*_n$ with the same ratio as before, just set $p^*_i = p_i / (1 - p^*_1)$

Comment: @BGM Thank you for your help, also yes i want the ratio to be kept in the same way, although since i'm not used to Mathematical notation (Sadly I'm pretty new to this), would you mind providing an example for me to understand if its not too much to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example: we have three possible outcomes $A,B,C$, with probability $0.5,0.3,0.2$ respectively. Note that $\mathbb P(B):\mathbb P(C)=3:2$, so we can say that $\mathbb P(B)=3k,\mathbb P(C)=2k$ where $k$ is a constant. If $\mathbb P(A)$ is changed to $0.8:$ \begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)+\mathbb P(C)&=1\longrightarrow 0.8+3k+2k=1\longrightarrow k=0.04
\end{align*}
So we have the new probabilities: $$\mathbb P(B)=3\times 0.04=0.12,\:\mathbb P(C)=2\times 0.04=0.08$$

Comment: Ah! Gotcha, now I get it, thank you very much!